# JetPack Compose is laggy

Tags: android, android-layout, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to make the UI with the jetpack compose but my component starts to lag after 5-10 second and the lag just increase continuously i am stuck.
I was making  a Expandable card view but i just stuck in between and then start again very bad experience

````
@ExperimentalMaterialApi
fun ExpandableCard(){
    var expandedState by remember{mutableStateOf(false)}
    val rotationState by animateFloatAsState(
        targetValue = if (expandedState) 180f else 0f)
    Card(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .animateContentSize(
                animationSpec = tween(
                    durationMillis = 300,
                    easing = LinearOutSlowInEasing
                )
            )
        ,shape = RoundedCornerShape(4.dp)
        ,onClick = {expandedState = !expandedState}
    )
    {
        Column(
            Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(12.dp)) {
            Row (verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically){
                Text(text = "Title Text",
                    modifier = Modifier.weight(6f),
                    fontSize = 22.sp,
                    fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                maxLines = 1,
                overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis)
                IconButton(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .alpha(ContentAlpha.medium)
                        .weight(1f)
                        .rotate(rotationState)
                    ,
                    onClick = { expandedState = !expandedState }) {
                    Icon(imageVector = Icons.Default.ArrowDropDown,
                        contentDescription = "Drop-down arrow")


                }
            }
            if (expandedState){
                Text(text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur " +
                        "adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. " +
                        "Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. " +
                        "Nulla quis sem at nibh" +
                        " elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris." +
                        " Fusce nec tellus sed augue semper porta. Mauris massa." +
                        " Vestibulum lacinia arcu eget nulla. Class aptent taciti" +
                        " sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos"
                        + " himenaeos"
                ,fontSize =  18.sp,
                fontWeight = FontWeight.Normal,
                maxLines = 4,
                overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis)
            }
        }
    }
}```
````

Comment: this code runs totally fine with max 15% cpu usage on my android phone with weak processor when constantly clicking. maybe problem is in an other part of the app. Have you tried running this code block on an empty project, does it still lags?

Answer (score 1):

you are testing it inside debug virsion.
make an apk and then compose will show you the true power of itself!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29855060)